# SqLite: LIMIT — выдаёт синтаксическую ошибку

Tags: php, sqlite3

Подскажите пожалуйста, как задать LIMIT, чтобы вывести на страницу определённое количество записей. Вот так не работает:

```
$stmt = $db->query('
                    SELECT a.*, count(*) AS conut, c.category AS category_name
                    FROM articles LIMIT 3 AS a JOIN categories AS c
                    ON a.category=c.id
                  ');
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Что можно сделать?

Comment: LIMIT - это самая последняя кляуза запроса. А у Вас она в середине.

Comment: Так тоже не работает: ошибки не выдаёт, но отображает почему-то только одну, самую последнюю запись (… ON a.category=c.id LIMIT 3)

Comment: Насколько помню функция count() возвращает количество записей запроса, по этому у вас одна строка, если вам нужно выводить строку количества категорий то проще делать вложенный запрос.

Comment: `SELECT a.*, (SELECT count(*) FROM articles WHERE category = a.category) AS count, c.category AS category_name FROM articles AS a JOIN categories AS c ON a.category=c.id  LIMIT 3` типа такого

Comment: Нет :) Нужно не количество категорий, а количество записей (a — статей). Но тем не менее большое спасибо, попробую отталкиваться от предложенного вами варианта.